# Perform bucketing properly on spark query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, bucket

Let's consider a dataset:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 33 |
| Adam | 32 |
| Zim | 41 |
| Muller | 62 |

Now, if we run this query on dataset `x`:

```
x.as("a").join(x.as("b")).where(
          $"b.age" - $"a.age" <= 10 and
          $"a.age" > $"b.age").show()
```

| name | age | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 33 | Zim | 41 |
| Adam | 32 | Max | 33 |
| Adam | 32 | Zim | 41 |

That is my desired result.

Now, conceptually if I have a very big dataset, I might want to use bucketing to reduce search space.

So, doing bucketing with:

```
val buck_x = x.withColumn("buc_age", floor($"age"/ 10))
```

which gives me:

| name | age | buck_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 33 | 3 |
| Adam | 32 | 3 |
| Zim | 41 | 4 |
| Muller | 62 | 6 |

After explode, I get the following result:

```
val exp_x = buck_x.withColumn("buc_age", explode(array($"buc_age" -1, $"buc_age", $"buc_age" + 1)))
```

| name | age | buck_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 33 | 2 |
| Max | 33 | 3 |
| Max | 33 | 4 |
| Adam | 32 | 2 |
| Adam | 32 | 3 |
| Adam | 32 | 4 |
| Zim | 41 | 3 |
| Zim | 41 | 4 |
| Zim | 41 | 5 |
| Muller | 62 | 5 |
| Muller | 62 | 6 |
| Muller | 62 | 7 |

Now, after final query,

```
exp_x.as("a").join(exp_x.as("b")).where(
          $"a.buc_age" === $"b.buc_age" and
          $"b.age" - $"a.age" <= 10 and
          $"b.age" > $"a.age").show()
```

I get the following result.

| name | age | buc_age | name | age | buc_age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Max | 33 | 3 | Zim | 41 | 3 |
| Max | 33 | 4 | Zim | 41 | 4 |
| Adam | 32 | 2 | Max | 33 | 2 |
| Adam | 32 | 3 | Zim | 41 | 3 |
| Adam | 32 | 3 | Max | 33 | 3 |
| Adam | 32 | 4 | Zim | 41 | 4 |
| Adam | 32 | 4 | Max | 33 | 4 |

Clearly, it's not the same as my expectation, I am getting more rows than expected. How to solve this while using bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Drop your bucketing columns and then select distinct rows, essentially undoing the duplication caused by explode:

```
exp_x.select(res1.columns.map(c => col(c).as(c + "_a")) : _*).join(exp_x.select(res1.columns.map(c => col(c).as(c + "_b")) : _*)).where(
          $"buc_age_a" === $"buc_age_b" and
          $"age_b" - $"age_a" <= 10 and
          $"age_b" > $"age_a").
          drop("buc_age_a", "buc_age_b").
          distinct.
          show

+------+-----+------+-----+
|name_a|age_a|name_b|age_b|
+------+-----+------+-----+
|  Adam|   32|   Zim|   41|
|  Adam|   32|   Max|   33|
|   Max|   33|   Zim|   41|
+------+-----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for an explode.

Instead, this approach unions two inner self joins. The two joins find cases where:

- A and B are in the same bucket, and B is older
- B is one bucket more, but no more than 10 years older

This should perform better than using the explode, since fewer comparisons are performed (because the sets being joined here are one third of the exploded size).

```scala
val namesDF = Seq(("Max", 33), ("Adam", 32), ("Zim", 41), ("Muller", 62)).toDF("name", "age")

val buck_x =  namesDF.withColumn("buc_age", floor($"age" / 10))

// same bucket where b is still older
val same = buck_x.as("a").join(buck_x.as("b"),  ($"a.buc_age" === $"b.buc_age" && $"b.age" > $"a.age"), "inner")

// different buckets -- b is one bucket higher but still no more than 10 ages different
val diff = buck_x.as("a").join(buck_x.as("b"),  ($"a.buc_age" + 1 === $"b.buc_age" && $"b.age" <= $"a.age" + 10), "inner")

val result = same.union(diff)
```

The result (you can do a `drop` to remove excess columns like in Charlie's answer):

```
result.show(false)
+----+---+-------+----+---+-------+
|name|age|buc_age|name|age|buc_age|
+----+---+-------+----+---+-------+
|Adam|32 |3      |Max |33 |3      |
|Max |33 |3      |Zim |41 |4      |
|Adam|32 |3      |Zim |41 |4      |
+----+---+-------+----+---+-------+
```